# Would this question be accepted?

Tags: discussion, support

I want to give money for the well-being of animals. I found many opportunities to send money in my country (Sweden) if I search the terms "swish ge pengar till katter". But I have no means to evaluate the different opportunities to send money. Is one better than the other?

Answer (score 3):

How to send money would be out of scope for a site about pets.  I understand that the money is for pets.

Comment: I found that there is a tag "charity" at another site https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charity

Comment: Also there are 1,700+ poss about [sending money](https://money.stackexchange.com/search?q=send+money) on that site.  That seems like a good place to ask.